# Do Facebook long-access page tokens need to be renewed?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm confused as to whether or not long-access page tokens from Facebook need to be renewed. Apparently Facebook has changed this at least once, and I'm not sure how the system works now. I created a long-access token using the instructions [here](http://logicum.co/getting-a-facebook-page-permanent-access-token/), which I need for a server-side application which needs to post as a Facebook page. Does this token ever need to be renewed? If so, is it possible to automatically renew it on the server side?

The accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651070/renew-long-lived-access-token-server-side) links to some Facebook documentation that apparently said that Facebook provides page tokens that do not expire, but the [link](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) no longer exists.

I'm using the [Python Facebook SDK](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk) if anyone wants to give me an example of how to renew a token (if needed).

Edit: Apparently to get the page token, you must also ask the graph api for /{pageId}?fields=access_token after following the previous instructions I linked.

Comment: I would suggest that you read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending . But the sort answer is yes access token can expire

Comment: On day 61 they expire, so the answer is yes, they must be renewed

Comment: If you create a long-lived Page Access Token in v1.0 of the Graph API via the Token exchange mechanism, it will be valid indefinitely. With Graph API v2.0 the maximun you can get is 60 days.